# ColorBox Pause Vido on Close

Tags: javascript, drupal-7, jquery-events, audiovideoplayback

I need help with a small bug on epacca.com

On the right you will see some images, if you click it, it pops-up a ColorBox with a OSM Player (MediaFront) for the video. When you close the ColorBox, the video keeps playing in FireFox. So there is a hook on ColorBox close. I just need the correct JS to pause the video.

The video API can be found here: http://mediafront.org/osmplayer/developer.html#.UIRpQ8XA9el I have been trying all sorts of things to try and get the video pause.

```
(function ($) {
    $(document).bind('cbox_closed', function(e){
        // Code here
    });
}(jQuery));
```